# .NET Core - Attachment causing Failure Sending Mail

Tags: c#, .net-core, smtp

I have the following code, which works when I don't have the attachment.add line. (I've blanked out the addresses & password).

Please help, I guess I'm doing something wrong with the attachment I'm just not sure what!

The inner exception is

> {System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'ReferenceReadStream'.    at
>   System.Net.Mime.MimeBasePart.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.Message.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMessageCallback(IAsyncResult result)}

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<String> PostProfilePicture(IFormFile file, int ID)
    {
        var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper() + ".png";
        try
        {
            var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            await sendEmail(stream, name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }

       return ""
    }

  public async Task sendEmail(Stream stream, String filename){
        var attachment = new Attachment(stream, filename);

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient

        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com", // set your SMTP server name here
            Port = 587, // Port 
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx")
        };

        var message = new MailMessage("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxx@gmail.com");


            message.Subject = "Hello Alec!!";
            message.Body = "How are you doing.";
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);




            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message was in the title, "Failure Sending Mail"

Comment: Oops. 

{System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ReferenceReadStream'.    at System.Net.Mime.MimeBasePart.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.Mail.Message.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMessageCallback(IAsyncResult result)}

Answer (score 0):

I think the stream needs to be readable, add

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<String> PostProfilePicture(IFormFile file, int ID)
{
    var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper() + ".png";
    try
    {
        await sendEmail(file, name); //send the file not the open read stream
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }

   return "";
}



public async Task sendEmail(IFormFile file, String filename){

        using(var stream = file.OpenReadStream()){ //You open your stream here
        var attachment = new Attachment(stream, filename);

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient

        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com", // set your SMTP server name here
            Port = 587, // Port 
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx")
    };

    var message = new MailMessage("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxx@gmail.com");


        message.Subject = "Hello Alec!!";
        message.Body = "How are you doing.";
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: My file comes from IFormFile, not sure how to implement that as I don't have a physical copy of the file.

Comment: The exception ObjectDisposedException you have is related to the OpenReadStream() disposed object. You should send the IFormFile into your sendEmail() method instead of the stream and then openreadstream inside the SendEmail method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the stream is no read to end:

Try:

```
    var fileContent = stream.ReadToEnd();
    var attachment = new Attachment(fileContent, filename);

    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
```

Perhaps You have to read the filcontent before calling SendEmail

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I am using MailKit library since Microsoft's System.Net.Smtp clients are deprecated going forward. I am attaching the IFormFile by opening its stream which I attach to MailKit's MimePart in the 2nd Function Attach below: MimePart AddAttachment(IFormFile attach).

```
    public void SendEmail(EmailDao mail)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        List<MemoryStream> memoryStreams = new List<MemoryStream>();
        var smtpServer = new Smtplient();
        try
        {
            //Send Email:
            smtpServer.Connect(_businessSmtpDetails.GetSection("SmtpServer").Value);
            var mailMessage = new MimeMessage();


            mailMessage.Subject = @"From " + mail.EmailFrom + " " + mail.EmailSubject;

            mailMessage.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(_businessSmtpDetails.GetSection("BusinessEmail").Value));

            if (mail.Attachment != null)
            {
                //memoryStream = ReadFileAttachment(mail.Attachment, new MemoryStream());

                // create an image attachment for the file located at path


                // now create the multipart/mixed container to hold the message text and the
                // image attachment
                var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
                multipart.Add(new TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) { Text = mail.EmailBody });

                var mimiPart = AddAttachment(mail.Attachment);

                multipart.Add(mimiPart);

                // now set the multipart/mixed as the message body
                mailMessage.Body = multipart;
            }
            if (mail.Attachments != null && mail.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
                foreach (var attach in mail.Attachments)
                {

                    //memoryStream = ReadFileAttachment(mail.Attachment, new MemoryStream());
                    //memoryStreams.Add(memoryStream);

                    // create an image attachment for the file located at path
                    var mimiPart = AddAttachment(attach);

                    multipart.Add(mimiPart);

                }
                multipart.Add(new TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) { Text = mail.EmailBody });
                // now set the multipart/mixed as the message body
                mailMessage.Body = multipart;
            }
            mail.EmailTo += string.Format(";{0}", _businessSmtpDetails.GetSection("BusinessEmail").Value);
            Array.ForEach<string>(mail.EmailTo.Split(new char[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), (p) =>
            {
                mailMessage.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(p));
            });
            smtpServer.Authenticate(_businessSmtpDetails.GetSection("NetworkUsername").Value, _businessSmtpDetails.GetSection("NetworkPassword").Value);
            smtpServer.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            smtpServer.Disconnect(true);
            if (memoryStream != null)
            {
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
            if(memoryStreams.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(var memStrm in memoryStreams)
                {
                    memStrm.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private MimePart AddAttachment(IFormFile attach)
    {
        var attachment = new MimePart("octet", attach.FileName.Substring(attach.FileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1))
        {
            Content = new MimeContent(attach.OpenReadStream()),
            ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Attachment),
            ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Default,
            FileName = attach.FileName
        };

        // now create the multipart/mixed container to hold the message text and the
        // image attachment
        return attachment;
    }
```